# U-SQL Python extension DataFrame Column Format

Tags: python, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am trying to use the Python Extension to run some code, but when I try to reference columns in the pandas dataframe, it says it cannot find the column:

```
if "hist_future_flag" not in [x.lower() for x in dfBLData.columns.values.tolist()]:
            ProcessSuccessFlag = False
            print('dfBLData (Input DataFrame) requires "hist_future_flag" column. Cols in dfBLData are: ')
            print(', '.join(dfBLData.columns.values.tolist()))
```

> dfBLData (Input DataFrame) requires ""hist_future_flag"" column. Cols in dfBLData are: 
>   b'geography', b'mitm_key', b'target', b'dow', b'time_key', b'hist_future_flag' ... [and so on]

So it looks like they are coming in as bytes, but when I try to convert the headers, python says they are strings and cannot be decoded!

Here is the relevant U-SQL I'm running:

```
@d = 
SELECT [geography], [mitm_key], [target], [dow], [time_key],[hist_future_flag]
FROM modeling.dbo.LandingZone
WHERE geography == 5;

@bl =
REDUCE @d
ON geography, mitm_key
PRODUCE 
time_key DateTime,
predict float,
hist_future_flag int
USING new Extension.Python.Reducer(pyScript:@myScript);

OUTPUT @bl
TO "/test_reducer.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv(outputHeader: true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have deployed new bits on 13th April 2017 were we make the changes to not to convert string to bytes. Please reinstall the extension and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out when using anything other than the "VALUES" method of selecting, the column name representation is "b'columnname'". It is basically a stringified representation of the column name as bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I forwarded this thread to the product team to take a look if it is already fixed and if not, that they will add a fix.